# $a^2b^2=b^2a^2 , a^3b^3=b^3a^3$ , then $G$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory

If in a group $G$ , $a^2b^2=b^2a^2 , a^3b^3=b^3a^3 , \forall a.b\in G$ , then how to prove that $G$ is abelian ? It is supposed to be some elementary manipulation but I can't figure it out , please help .

Comment: Can you show that $ab^{-2}=b^{-2}a$ from the hypothesis given?

Comment: what after that @HassanMuhammad